# Disable dictionary popup

Tags: keyboard, languages

When I'm typing some text and I tap a word that doesn't exist, a popup shows up offering alternative words (as well as a "delete" and an "add to dictionary" option).

This feature is useless for me, because the suggestions don't take into consideration the current language, which makes them strictly worse than the suggestions already displayed by the keyboard.

The problem is that this popup covers up the keyboard's suggestions (which are the reason why I tapped the word in the first place) along with half the keyboard. This forces me to tap on some other region of the screen so that the popup will close and allow me to see the keyboard suggestions.

Is there a way to disable this popup entirely?

Comment: Problem is you have installed G-Board. Uninstall it, and you are back to basics without the enoying popup dictionary :-)

Comment: How do you know OP is using GBoard, if I may? How can you be sure?

Comment: I have the same problem since the latest Android update.  It's entirely redundant because the keyboard itself (swiftkey) already offers dictionary suggestions, but this new Android one is so huge it blocks the view of half my keyboard.

Comment: It is not only useless for you, it is useless for everyone! probably the programmer who implemented this and even his boss never used an android device in their life and were only familiar with iOS environment.

Comment: It's a really annoying smart-ass feature. The Android OS devs need to learn UX. I'm not using Gboard but can't find a way to turn it off. Android 13, 2023.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't disable the pop-up alone, but there are some other options:-

1. You can disable the spell-checker completely. If your keyboard already provides all the spell-check functionality you need, then this might be a good option for you. In **Language & input** in the device settings, untick **Spell checker**. This will disable the pop-up and the red underlining for misspelled words.
2. You can change the language of the spell-checker. From **Language and input** in the device settings, click the settings icon next to **Spell checker**, then the globe icon on the next screen. You can only have one language at a time in the default spell-checker, so this might not be helpful.
3. You can install a replacement spell-checker. Android allows other apps to provide the spell-check functionality in place of the built-in spell-checker. A different spell-checker might allow you to have more than one language enabled. Once you've installed the spell-checker, enable it from the same screen described in the above alternative.

In case some visitors are confused about the diffrence between the keyboard and the spell-checker, see this screenshot, from the Android developers' site:

[image: screenshot of Android spell-checker]

The red underlining, and the vertical menu of suggested corrections, are both provided by the spell-checker. Most soft-keyboards also include a list of suggested word completions, which are usually in a horizontal line above the keyboard. Here you can see ":" and ";", and the rest are hidden by the spell-checker's pop-up.

Comment: Is the "spell checker" displaying **additional** suggestions to those the keyboard presents, in a popup? I've never seen such. Could you include an explanation of the background, please?

Comment: @Izzy maybe it only happens if you use a non-default keyboard. It's a white popup with a vertical list of around 7 words. It's downwards vertical, so it covers the keyboard. It only happens if you tap on a word that the spell checker marked as wrong. Disabling the spell checker worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your updates, both. @BruceConnor: I use non-default keyboards as well. But maybe I've disabled that stuff "long ago" and just don't remember :)

Comment: This doesn't work in MIUI 8 because the checkbox to enable/disable the Spell Checker does not exist. The reason why it doesn't exist is beyond me.

Comment: @GuiImamura If that's a problem for you, you could ask a new question that's specific to MIUI 8. Link to this question if it helps to explain the problem.

Comment: If this is relevant to anyone, here's my new question: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/166169/57685

Comment: This is added in android 10, Do you know where this popup coming from (which app)? so we can report hell bug out of it? This is a feature for iOS devices that do not have a suggestion bar! probably developer only used iOS in their life ever!