# MIUI 7/8 has no way to disable the global Google Spell Check

Tags: miui, gboard, spell-check

I am the happy owner of a brand new Xiaomi Redmi 3 Prime. It comes with the MIUI 7, and there is a free upgrade to MIUI 8 via the built-in upgrade software.

My only complaint, so far, is that it comes with a utterly annoying spell checker that applies globally to all text inputs, and has no user-friendly way to disable it, as you'll see in the following link. As I found out, this is a problem in the MIUI system. I've tried [all the solutions from this thread](https://xiaomi.eu/community/threads/unable-to-turn-off-spell-checker-in-settings.28466/), but to no avail:

- Trying to set the `spell_checker_enabled` to `0` requires `su`, and it says `su` couldn't be found, either from Terminator Emulator for Android and from ADB remote shell.
- Trying to set the Google Keyboard language to QWERTY worked, untill I decided to disable this Keyboard, because I won't be using it.
- Disabling Google Keyboard Autocorrection doesn't work.
- In the Google Keyboard app detail from system configuration, it doesn't let me disable it.

Would be really glad to disable it.

Side note: this is irrelevant to this question, but as I tried to install minimal ADB and Fastboot on my Ubuntu, it suggested me to run `apt-get -f install` because there were unmet dependencies. After I did it and rebooted my laptop, my graphical UI was broken and I've just installed a fresh Ubuntu on it.

Comment: To access `su` you need to root the device.

Comment: @MatthewRead Well. I can't root it via KingoRoot because it fails at 90% of its rooting routine, and hadn't had time to read the full flashing instructions yet. Any wasy way?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you enabled USB debugging on your phone? Is your phone listed when you enter "adb devices" in cmd? When you connect your phone to your PC, your phone should ask for a confirmation to start USB debugging.

The problem I had with [these instructions](https://xiaomi.eu/community/threads/unable-to-turn-off-spell-checker-in-settings.28466/#post-264548) was that my phone didn't actually connect to my PC, so ADB did not recognize the device.

[After installing PDA-net on my PC](http://pdanet.co/a/), that issue was resolved. It installs the correct drivers.

Also make sure that in the USB debugging menu on your phone, you have enabled "USB debugging (security settings)" (you'll need a Mi account).

Then, enter `adb shell`, and `settings put secure spell_checker_enabled 0`. That should do it.

**Complete instructions**

1. Enable developer options on your phone (search for it in the settings app)
2. Enable USB debugging on your phone in the settings app
3. *(This might not be required)* Enable "USB debugging (security settings)" in the same menu.
4. Install ADB on your PC (use your favorite search engine to look up "ADB, Fastboot and Drivers - 15 seconds ADB Installer". I'm not allowed to post more than 3 URLs here)
5. Open a command prompt (`cmd`) and type `cd [folder path where adb was installed]`.
6. Connect your phone through USB. Confirm USB debugging on your phone. If you don't get the confirmation window, download and install PDA-net on your PC.
7. Enter `adb shell`.
8. Enter `settings put secure spell_checker_enabled 0`. **Done.** Don't forget to disable USB debugging after you're done.

Comment: Yes and yes. It doesn't find the command `su`, meaning it's not rooted. If I'm not mistaken, the last command in your recipe requires SU previleges.

Answer (score 0):

(I am using Swiftkey Keyboard)

Google Play Store - Help & Feedback - Browse all articles - Delete or disable apps on Android - Tap to go to Application Settings - Gboard - Disable

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the solution, please watch the video carefully and do exactly as shown, it's easy and I was surprised that the app that supposedly only creates shortcuts in this case add the ability to disable system apps on miui 8.
https://youtu.be/-ywkVg9YzgI

Comment: Although external links are welcome in answers as a reference, it is required to at least summarize the operations needing to be done, although detailed instructions are preferred. Please see https://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer for more information on how to answer a question properly.